# Issue with cell formulae in openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

I have an excel file with a simple formula in range L5:L10, as follows:

```
=IF(E5="LONG",(I5-G5)*F5,(G5-I5)*F5)
...
=IF(E10="LONG",(I10-G10)*F10,(G10-I10)*F10)
```

When using `Cell.value` to access the formulae in the range as follows:

```
for c in ws['L5':'L10']: print c[0].value
```

I get the following output:

```
=IF(E5="LONG",(I5-G5)*F5,(G5-I5)*F5)
=IF(E6="LONG",(I6-G6)*F6,(G6-I6)*F6)
=
=
=
=
```

As you can see, L7 ~ L10 are reported as being empty formulae, but this is not the case in the file.

I am using the latest version from Mercurial (2.1). Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, I didn't stumble across this question until after I asked about an extremely similar issue:

[openpyxl returning empty cell values for formula series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738584/openpyxl-returning-empty-cell-values-for-formula-series)

I'd hazard that these are duplicates but as someone was able to answer it on my thread, I figured I should provide a link to a potential solution until one of the questions gets marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

When formulae are applied to a range of cells in Excel it sometimes uses an optimisation to store only a reference to the formula. Openpyxl preserves this but doesn't unpack it. It's difficult to say more without having a file to look at. Please submit a bug if you think there is one.