# openpyxl returning empty cell values for formula series

Tags: python, openpyxl

Vitals: python 3.4.3  | openpyxl 2.2.3 | Excel 2013

Like everyone knows you can use Excel's fill handle to quickly set up a number series down a column [1,2,3,4,5,6,etc] and this works with formula as well [=sum(B1,C1), =sum(B2,C2), =sum(B3,C3), etc]. However when I attempt to use openpyxl to nab formula added using the fill handle in Excel, those cells are reported to be empty.

It didn't work with my original code so I created a simple script containing this:

```
for row in ws.rows:
  for cell in row:
    print('my value is:',cell.value)
```

And ran it against this tiny (aww) Excel file. I used the fill handle on A1 to populate A2-A5 with formulas. (I'm just showing the formula for clarity, what I actually see in column A are the results.)

```
#      A       B   C
1 =SUM(B1:C1)  1   2
2 =SUM(B2:C2)  10  20
3 =SUM(B3:C3)  20  25
4 =SUM(B4:C4)  90  42
5 =SUM(B5:C5)  64  4
```

This was the output in console:

```
my value is: =SUM(B1:C1)
my value is: 1
my value is: 2
my value is: =SUM(B2:C2)
my value is: 10
my value is: 20
my value is: =
my value is: 20
my value is: 25
my value is: =
my value is: 90
my value is: 42
my value is: =
my value is: 64
my value is: 4
```

openpyxl reads the formula in A1 and A2 but not A3-A5. I tried this snippet against a couple of simple number series and openpyxl didn't have a problem reading those cells...the issue just seems to be with formulas. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I got the same problem (just the initial =) instead of whole formula. (Reading values is ok though)

Comment: Cool beans, I'll give it a shot and see if I can make it work with Python 3.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update 3/23/16

This issue has been resolved in recent versions of `openpyxl` (2.3, and beyond, I believe) [PR request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613272/how-to-access-the-real-value-of-a-cell-using-the-openpyxl-module-for-python)

---

This is a known shortcoming of `openpyxl` ([bug report](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issue/435/incomplete-read-with-extended-cells)). The short answer is that when you drag a formula down or across, Excel uses a "shared formula," which cannot be parsed by `openpyxl`. If you really need this functionality, you may want to try [`xlrd`](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd).

---

### Edit:

This was bugging me, so here's a very hackish workaround (Tested on Python 2.7). First you have to get Robin Macharg's Excel formula parser [from here](http://www.ewbi.com/ewbi.develop/samples/jsport_nonEAT.html). Save it somewhere in your Python path as `xlparse.py`. Now, run the code [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/felipeochoa/f053473a8c4788bd0e74#file-sharedpyxl-py), and you should be able to use the `get_formula` function to get the formula for any cell. In most cases, the function simply returns `cell.value`, but whenever the function encounters a shared formula, it gives the correct value.

**Note:**
The monkeypatch to `openpyxl.reader.worksheet.Worksheet` is so that `openpyxl.load_workbook` uses our patched class. Make sure to run this code before calling `load_workbook`. If you are creating the workbook a different way, you'll have to patch `Worksheet` in the appropriate place.

Comment: I don't know if this is a problem on my end or not (I'm still fairly new to programming) but sharedpyxl kicks back the following error when it tries to process cell A3 of the sample Excel spreadsheet I used in my original post:
**openpyxl.utils.exceptions.CellCoordinatesException: Invalid cell coordinates (B2:C2)** when it hits this line 'col, row = openpyxl.utils.coordinate_from_string(addr)' inside the R1C1Converter class.

Comment: Oh I see. I think the problem's with `sharedpyxl`, let me take another crack at it and post back.

Comment: Ok -- the problem was with the range of cells. I've updated the Gist. Give it another try and let me know if it works

Comment: I got the same error when I ran it again but after double-checking the Gist revision history, I'm still seeing a version of sharedpyxl last updated yesterday (5 total), even after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Oops didn't actually hit submit. Try now

Comment: Bingo! I've tested it with some more complex shared formulae and it looks to be working perfectly.Thank you so much for your help! For anyone wondering about compatibility with Python 3, I just ran sharedpyxl and xlparse.py through 2to3.py with the -w switch and it ran without issue on Python 3.4.3. Do you think the question title should be updated to include the proper verbiage ('shared formulae' rather than 'formula series')?