# openpyxl: Formulas read as blanks in some (key use) cases

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

My code downloads a .xlsx file from google drive (using pydrive), finds some blank cells with pandas, and fills in those blank cells with openpyxl.

When I open the openpyxl altered file, everything looks great.  However, when I use the pandas read_excel function, all cells that have equations are read as blanks.  I suspect the issue is with openpyxl because when I preview the file on drive, those cells are blank.  There is no issue with a file that openpyxl hasn't touched.

It looks like my issue is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738584/openpyxl-returning-empty-cell-values-for-formula-series), but since my objective is just to leave the formulas untouched (I only want to fill blank cells), I don't really want to parse the formulas and I'm not really sure how or if to apply [Felipe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754254/felipe) fix.

I'd like to be able to download the file to plot it with bokeh, and users and python will both be editing the program, so I'd really like pandas to be able to read the equations whether its a user modified file or an openpyxl modified file.  The equations in the file were click and drag "shared equations", and I'd like to keep it that way if possible so ideally I'd like to avoid using `data_only=True`.  I tried specifying `data_only=False`, but this didn't appear to change anything.

I'm using openpyxl <strike>2.3.5</strike> 2.4, and I keep excel closed when code is running.

Versions of the file before and after openpyxl modification are [available here](https://github.com/manewton/BioReactor-Data-Logging/tree/master/Reference).

My code is here, all openpyxl code is isolated to : 
    # Import Libraries
    import datetime
    import imp
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    from itertools import islice
    # Relative imports for bokeh interaction

```
dl = imp.load_source('downloader', os.getcwd() +
                      '/Project/downloader.py')
gdu = imp.load_source('googledriveutils', os.getcwd() +
                      '/Project/googledriveutils.py')
remove_file = gdu.remove_file
find_folderid = gdu.find_folderid
get_file_list = gdu.get_file_list


# Define constants
COL_LABEL = '\nProbe - '
# TODO: ORP PROBE: REVISE THIS DATE when orp probe is added
IGNORE_BEFORE = pd.to_datetime('5.24.2016')
PROBE_DICT = {'DO (mg/L)': 'DO mg/L',
              'pH': 'pH',
              'NH4+ (mgN/L)': 'Ammonium',
              'ORP (mV)': 'ORP mV'}
TS = '\nTimestamps'


def save_to_workbook(newval,
                     date,
                     header,
                     rows_to_skip=12,
                     wbname='temp.xlsx',
                     sheet_name='Reactor Data'):
    wb = load_workbook(wbname)
    ws = wb[sheet_name]
    for cell in ws[rows_to_skip+1]:
        # TODO: Error if header isn't found
        if cell.value == header:
            colno = cell.col_idx
            break

    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=rows_to_skip+1, min_col=1, max_col=1):
        for cell in row:
        # TODO: Error if date isn't found
            if cell.value == date:
                rowno = cell.row
                break

    ws.cell(row=rowno, column=colno).value = newval
    wb.save(wbname)


    return df





def find_r1masterfile():
    # Navigate through the directories
    wlab_fid = find_folderid('Winkler Lab', 'root')
    kp_fid = find_folderid('KathrynsProjects', wlab_fid)
    amxrct_fid = find_folderid('Anammox Reactor', kp_fid)
    trials_fid = find_folderid('Reactor Trials', amxrct_fid)
    # List files in directory
    file_list = get_file_list(trials_fid)
    for afile in file_list:
        if afile['title'] == 'AMX RCT.xlsx':
            # Return the file we asked for
                return afile
        # TODO: error if there was no file with that name


def save_r1masterfile(csv, rows_to_skip=12, filename='temp.xlsx', sheet_name='Reactor Data'):
    # Get the file we want
    master_file = find_r1masterfile()
    try:
        master_file.GetContentFile(filename)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Warning: Something wrong with file R1 Master File."
        print str(e)
        # TODO: add an email alarm to responsible user

    if csv:
        return master_file
    else:
        # convert to dataframe
        wb = load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
        ws = wb[sheet_name]
        print ws["B14"].value
        data = ws.values
        data = list(data)[rows_to_skip:]
        cols = list(data[0])
        del cols[0]
        del data[0]
        idx = [r[0] for r in data]
        data = (islice(r, 1, None) for r in data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=cols)
        print df.dropna(how='all')
        remove_file(filename)
        return df


def upload_r1masterfile(filename='temp.xlsx'):
    # Get the file we want
    master_file = find_r1masterfile()
    try:
        master_file.SetContentFile(filename)
        master_file.Upload()
    except Exception, e:
        print "Warning: Something wrong with file R1 Master File."
        print str(e)
        # TODO: add an email alarm to responsible user


def populate_r1masterfile(rows_to_skip=12, filename='temp.xlsx'):
    # Get the R1 master file as a file
    save_r1masterfile(True)
    # Convert the juicy stuff to a dataframe
    masterdf = pd.read_excel(filename,
                             sheetname='Reactor Data',
                             encoding="utf-16",
                             skiprows=rows_to_skip,
                             sep='\t',
                             index_col='Date',
                             keep_default_na=False,
                             na_values=['-1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '1.#IND',
                             '-1.#QNAN', '','N/A', '#NA', 'NA'
                             'NULL', 'NaN', '-NaN', 'nan', '-nan'])
    # Find what we will populate with probe data
    # Find timestamps
    ts_columns = [col for col in masterdf.columns if TS in col]
    tsdf = masterdf[ts_columns]
    # Find probes, ignore before given date
    probe_columns = [col for col in masterdf.columns if COL_LABEL in col]
    probedf = masterdf[probe_columns]
    probedf = probedf[masterdf.index > IGNORE_BEFORE]
    # Find Indices and column labels of blank values
    stackdf = probedf.stack(dropna=False)
    empty = stackdf[stackdf.isnull()].index.tolist()

    # For each blank look for the probe, time & date of cycle, and return val
    for each in empty:
        probe, time = each[1].split(COL_LABEL)
        time = tsdf.loc[each[0], time+TS]
        ts = each[0]+pd.DateOffset(hour=time.hour, minute=time.minute)
        val = dl.get_val_from(1, ts, PROBE_DICT.get(probe))
        probedf.set_value(each[0], each[1], val)
        # Save that value to the workbook
        save_to_workbook(val, each[0], each[1])
    upload_r1masterfile()
    print 'Master file updated. ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    remove_file('temp.xlsx')
    return probedf
```

## UPDATE

I modified my code as per Charlie's suggestions (updated above).  But I'm still getting Nones in the dataframe.  To provide a more specific example, why is it when I run this code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('AMX RCT mod.xlsx', data_only=True)
ws = wb['Reactor Data']
print 'Value of B14 Formula is: ' + str(ws["B14"].value)
```

With [this file](https://github.com/manewton/BioReactor-Data-Logging/blob/master/Reference/AMX%20RCT%20mod.xlsx), I get back?:

```
Value of B14 Formula is: None
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example of what you mean and possibly a sample file? 2.3 includes Felipe's formula translation code. But if you're wanting to work with Pandas you might want to try 2.4 which will let you go straight from a worksheet to a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Using openpyxl 2.4 you might be able to do what you need in a single pass. I've taken your first function and adapted it.

```
from itertools import islice
from pandas import DataFrame

def save_to_workbook(newval,
                     date,
                     header,
                     rows_to_skip=12,
                     wbname='temp.xlsx',
                     sheet_name='Reactor Data'):
    wb = load_workbook(wbname)
    ws = wb[sheet_name]
    rowno = None
    colno = None
    for cell in ws[1]:
        # TODO: Error if header isn't found
        if cell.value == header:
            colno = col

    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=rows_to_skip+1, min_col=1, max_col=1):
        for cell in row:
        # TODO: Error if date isn't found
            if cell.value == date:
                rowno = row
                break

    # TODO: Fix this
    ws.cell(row=rowno, column=colno).value = newval

    # convert to dataframe
    data = ws.values
    cols = next(data)[1:]
    data = list(data)
    idx = [r[0] for r in data]
    data = (islice(r, 1, None) for r in data)
    df = DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=cols)

    return df
```

This probably doesn't do everything you want but will hopefully get you started. It also avoids saving and parsing a whole workbook which could make it quite a bit faster.

To work with openpyxl 2.4 you will either need to do `pip install -U --pre openpyxl` or work with a checkout.

For further information on using openpyxl and pandas together please see the [documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html).

Comment: Hi Charlie!  Thanks so much for your response.  This really helped me think of some better ways to structure my code.  However, I am 'None' back when I ask for a value with a formula.  Any more hints?

Comment: er, where are you "asking for a value with a formula"? I suggest this might make more sense on the mailing list and if you can supply a file.

Comment: Sending to the mailing list.  To clarify, when you say "supply a file" do you mean my .py file or my .xlsx file?

Comment: Whatever you've got and can share. "Write my code" requests for me are sternly frowned upon.

Comment: Happy to share all I have of course, for future googlers: everything available on the linked git repo above.

Answer (score 0):

Charlie's Answer from the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/0NL45GhxSKc):

> So, if you want to keep the formulae then you must not use data only mode.
>   As previously stated, openpyxl never evaluates formulae so if you want to
>   know value of A3 you *must* pass the file to an application such as Excel
>   or OpenOffice — you can run OpenOffice headless for this kind of thing or
>   use xlwings for Excel — that does do formula evaluation. You could then
>   read this file in data only mode to see the result of the calculation.
>   Alternatively you could try using something like PyCel to do the
>   evaluation for you. But, basically if you want to do calculations: do them
>   in Python.

As per his suggestion, my workaround was to redo all the calculations column by column as they are done in the excel file.  I.E. For excel File like this:

```
        col1 col2   col3    col4
row1    1    3      =A1+B1  =1+3
row2    2    4      =A2+B2  =2+4
```

I import it as a dataframe like this (to maintain equations as a string):

```
wb = load_workbook(filename, data_only=False)
ws = wb[sheet_name]
data = ws.values
cols = next(data)[1:]
data = list(data)
idx = [r[0] for r in data]
data = (islice(r, 1, None) for r in data)
df = DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=cols)
```

And then do the following:

```
parse_excel = lambda x: eval(str(x)[1:]) if isinstance(x, str) else x
for col in df.columns:
    try:
        df[col] = df[col].map(parse_excel)
    except:
        pass
df['col3'] = df['col2']+df['col1']
```

I'm certain this is maybe the clumsiest way to do this, but it works for now.